# php random image where width equals

Tags: php, arrays, image, width

I currently have this snippet which spits out a random image

```
$imgDir  = 'images/';
$images  = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randimg = $images[array_rand($images)];
```

but I want the image to be a certain width (600px), rather then warping images by using CSS is there a way the image width can be checked using PHP incorporating the code snippet above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can go through each individual file and check its size with [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/getimagesize).

That's of course a very expensive operation to do every time. Instead, do this once and make the size part of the filename (e.g. `foobar_500.jpg`) and `glob` for that, or use a database to organize your images to begin with where you can save such metadata and query for it.

Comment: Thank you deceze, going to go with the database option and use a RAND() query. (2mins b4 I can mark as answer)

Answer (score 0):

This will make sure you only select a random images from the images that have width 600

```
$imgDir = 'images/';
$images = glob($imgDir . '*.{jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);

$arr_images_600 = array();
foreach ($images as $img)
{
  list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img);
  if ($width == 600) { $arr_images_600[] = $img; }
}
$randimg = $images[array_rand($arr_images_600)];
```

Comment: Thank you but I think I will go with deceze answer of storing image width in database and call it using a RAND() query as like he said getimagesize is an expensive operation especially when I have over 50,000 images.